# After I swap variables , they return to it's original values

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to implement Euclid’s Algorithm

```
def gcd(num1, num2):
    if num2 > num1:
        num1, num2 = num2, num1
    while num1 % num2 != 0:
        num1 %= num2
        gcd(num1, num2)
return num2
```

when if statement get executed , the value of  num1 and num1 inside the while loop remain the same ( as there is no if statement)

I want to keep num1 always bigger than num2 but  , the code run as there is no if statement . why ?

Comment: Why are you nesting a function call?

Comment: it's Euclid’s Algorithm , I want to make the procedure inside the while loop till i get num1%num2 == 0

Comment: Do you understand what nesting the function call does?

Comment: yup ,, if there is anything ambiguous , tell me about it

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure you don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two ways to this: In a while loop and recursive. It looks like you mixed them up.
The while version would be:

```
def gcd(a,b):
   while b:
      a,b = b, a % b
   return a
```

The recursive version would be something like this:

```
def gcd(a,b):
   if b == 0:
      return a
   else:
      return gcd(b, a % b)
```

Note that if you call a function within a function, you have to make sure that there is a termination criteria such as if `b == 0` and that you return the function call. The reason why in your case nothing is happening is because the result of your nested function calls are not being passed back to the outer function call.